# How can I compare items in 2 ListView controls and display the missing items?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm coding a program in c#. I have 2 `ListView` controls. `listview1` is getting `TagName` and `TagID` from mysql database. `listview2` is getting `TagName` from an external device. I would like to compare the `TagName` fields from the 2 `listviews` and display a `MessageBox` with the missing items if `listview2` has missing items that are shown in `listview1`. How do I go around doing this?

So far i've tried this:

```
LstView.Sort();
ListViewDatabase.Sort();
if (ListViewDatabase.Items.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ListViewDatabase.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        string t = ListViewDatabase.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text;

        for (int j = 0; j < LstView.Items.Count; j++)
        {
            if (t != LstView.Items[j].SubItems[1].Text)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Missing Tag" + LstView.Items[j].SubItems[1].Text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this just shows all the tags in `listview2` and not the ones that are missing. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use such linq query to get items which are present in `listView1` but are absent in `listView2`:

```
var diff = listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(x => x.Text)
                    .Except(listView2.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(x => x.Text));
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} Missing.", string.Join(",", diff)));
```

Comment: Using [`Cast<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx) is really useful to extract `IEnumerable<T>` from `IEnumerable`. Then you can simply query the result. It's enough to use the type of elements instead of `T`.

Comment: I'm kinda new to linq. So how do i select the subitems in a listview?

Comment: So it should be like this?            var diff = ListViewDatabase.SubItems.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(x => x.Text)
                     .Except(LstView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(x => x.Text));
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} Missing.", string.Join(",", diff)));

Comment: If you want to get difference based on `SubItem[1]`, then it's enough to use `x => x.SubItems[1].Text` instead of `x => x.Text`.

Comment: So listview1 has a few items, but i just want to compare 1 item which is tagname. Same for listview2.

Comment: So it seems my previous comment which lets you to get difference based on a sub item is what you are looking for. Isn't it?

Comment: Exactly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, just modify it based on your required fields and according to the name of the controls.

```
List<string> list1 = listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                        .Select(item => item.Text)
                        .ToList();
List<string> list2 = listView2.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                        .Select(item => item.Text)
                        .ToList();
var commonUsers = list1.Select(a => a.Text).Intersect(list2.Select(b => b.Text)); // or use .Except to get the opposite
```

Comment: The OP wants the missing items not the shared/common items

Comment: @Plutonix Just eddited